# Increase buffer size in server/client in Kryonet

Tags: java, kryo, kryonet

How do I increase the buffer size in Server/Client constructor in Kryonet?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pass larger values than the defaults to the overloaded constructors.

`new Client()` is equivalent to `new Client(8192, 2048)`

`new Server()` is equivalent to `new Server(16384, 2048)`

See the [kryonet Javadocs](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.esotericsoftware/kryonet/latest/index.html) for more details.

Comment: Any Idea how to solve this issue ? https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryonet/issues/134#issuecomment-333369190